# PHP Multithreaded Socket Server child threads wont die

Tags: php, multithreading, sockets

I am using the lib:

https://github.com/lukaszkujawa/php-multithreaded-socket-server

And after adding exit(0); after the client disconnects I end up with lots of processes called: [php-cgi] piling up and they don't exit until the main server exits.

I have been trying to get this working for a week now and I am at a loss. I've commented an issue: https://github.com/lukaszkujawa/php-multithreaded-socket-server/issues/7

But I thought I would post here and hopefully get this fixed.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've got a fix, hopefully it doesn't have any long-term negative consequences.

In the "onConnect" function I made the following changes:

```
if ($pid == -1) {
    _echo('could not fork');
    die();
} else if ($pid) {
    // parent process handles client
} else {
    return;// new child handles next connection
}
```

And added "exit(0);" at the very end of the function.

Memory seems stable and no extra threads after the connection is closed.